# `fft` dramatic slowdown upon multiplying by `scipy.signal` window

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
from scipy.fft import fft
from timeit import default_timer as dtime

dtype = 'float32'
n_fft = 598
A = np.random.randn(n_fft, 160000).astype(dtype)
v0 = sig.windows.dpss(n_fft, 4).astype(dtype)
v1 = sig.windows.dpss(n_fft, n_fft // 8).astype(dtype)
v = v1

#%%###############################################################
t0 = dtime()
fft(A)
print(dtime() - t0)

A *= v.reshape(-1, 1)
#%%###############################################################
t0 = dtime()
fft(A)
print(dtime() - t0)
```

```
>>> 1.3161122000001342
>>> 4.751361799999813
```

Equal if using `v = v0` or `dtype = 'float64'` instead. Why does this happen? ([more times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35XrR.png))

*Note*: a workaround is `v = v1 + 1`, `v -= 1`, but this shouldn't be necessary... filed [Issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13764).

Win 10 x64, numpy 1.18.5, scipy 1.6.1, Python 3.7.9.

Comment: With NumPy FFT the times are about the same. With SciPy FFT I see a difference as well, but not as big: 1.2s to 1.9s. NumPy FFT is significantly slower...

Comment: @CrisLuengo scipy's fft is generally faster and supports single precision unlike numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by denormals (extremely small non-zero numbers) which make some CPU instructions run much slower; [details](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13764#issuecomment-809518408). Workaround is to zero them manually, as in `+1/-1`, or 'safely' via e.g. [ftz](https://github.com/rmcgibbo/ftz) (and *after* type casting):

```py
from ftz import ftz

ftz(v)
A *= v.reshape(-1, 1)

t0 = dtime()
fft(A)
print(dtime() - t0)
```

```
>>> 1.4638332999998056
>>> 1.4597183999999288
```